# How to rename a Bluemix namespace (container registry)?

Tags: docker, namespaces, containers, ibm-cloud, container-registry

I've set up a namespace for my container registry. I tried creating my first docker container. However, now I would like to change the namespace. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. According to [IBM Containers Docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_planning.html)

> The first time that you create a container within an organization, you are prompted to enter a name for the namespace that is associated with the private Bluemix repository. The namespace is used to generate a unique URL that you use to access your private Bluemix repository. The URL is required whenever you perform an action, such as a pull request or a push request of an image, to the repository. [...]
>
> The name cannot be changed after it is set for an organization.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace management is now possible in the IBM Bluemix Container Registry using the `container-registry` plugin for the `bx` command.

There isn't a direct rename option but you can:

- `bx cr namespace-list` - list all the namespace in your Bluemix account
- `bx cr namespace-add` - add a new namespace to your Bluemix account
- `bx cr namespace-rm` - remove a namespace from your Bluemix account

Namespaces are visible to all users in your Bluemix account.

Note that when you delete a namespace with `bx cr namespace-rm`, all images in that namespace are deleted from the registry.

Read the docs [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/registry_setup_cli_namespace.html#registry_cli_install).