# How can I change the private namespace with the IBM Containers-Registry at Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

I wonder how I can change the private namespace with the IBM Containers-Registry at Bluemix.

I do not find any function do this. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Regards,

Christian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a Bluemix namespace (container registry)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984788/how-to-rename-a-bluemix-namespace-container-registry)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such renaming feature.
What I did in the past was remove all images and running container. Delete the Space I was using for containers.

Then I waited a day and created again the Space with the same name, and I had to create a again the Container Registry namespace.

Hope this helps to you too.

Answer (score 0):

Once set, the registry namespace can’t be changed. If you can make a new organization, that’s another opportunity for a new registry name.

Answer (score 0):

as per the official documentation, once the namespace is created, it cannot be changed but can only be deleted. here is the documentation link: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_planning.html#container_planning_namespace